# SAML plug in for apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, ping, saml, saml-2.0

I'm new to `SAML` and need some help. I'm trying to implement `SSO` authentication using `SMAL 2.0` for our web application which is on `apache 2.4` (`AWS`). I have got in touch w/ `SSO` team and they are asking me to provide SP entity ID, `ACS` (end point URL) and Attributes to be passed. In our organization, `SSO` team is separate and assume they are `IDP`.

As I understand once I install `SAML` plug in, I would be able to generate `SP` entity `ID` and `ACS`. Can someone let me know from where I should be installing `SAML` plug in?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could either implement the SAML SP as part of Apache http server, e.g. using mod_auth_mellon (https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon/wiki), or if your web-app is php-based you could make your app act as SP using simpleSamplPHP (https://simplesamlphp.org/) or if your web-app is Java-based you can make your app act as SP by using Spring Security SAML extension. Alternatively you could use OpenIG (https://forgerock.org/openig/) as frontent to your app, it also includes a SAML SP.

Comment: my web-app is php based. I have installed simplesamlphp but I am unable to understand what changes I will have to make in my existing apache config file which is currently supporting basic authentication. I appreciate if you can help me with this. Also my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253189/how-apache-know-that-saml-response-is-authenticated